# Custom Regular Expression not validating on the client side

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have build a custom attribute to validate on the client side a positive decimal value. The problem is that when I apply the regular expression directly to the property, it works fine, but when I use the custom attribute, it does not work.

Working mode:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?!0?(,0?0)?$)([0-9]{0,3}(,[0-9]{1,2})?)?$", ErrorMessage = "Largura inválida.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Largura obrigatória.")]
    [Display(Name = "Formato Aberto")]
    public decimal SizeOpenedWidth { get; set; }
```

Custom Attribute:

```
public class PositiveDecimalAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public PositiveDecimalAttribute() : base("^(?!0?(,0?0)?$)([0-9]{0,3}(,[0-9]{1,2})?)?$") { }
}
```

Integrated in the property:

```
    [PositiveDecimal(ErrorMessage = "Largura inválida.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Largura obrigatória.")]
    [Display(Name = "Formato Aberto")]
    public decimal SizeOpenedWidth { get; set; }
```

In the second one, client side validation presents the error message:

```
The field Formato Aberto must be a number.
```

Do I need to integrate the new attribute on the client side validation?

Comment: Have you registered this in `global.asax`?

Comment: Hi thanks, no. What do I have to include in global.asax?

Comment: In `Application_Start()` - add `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(PositiveDecimalAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));`

Comment: Just like that? :) It's working! Do I have to do this for every custom attribute?

Comment: If its inherited from an existing `RegularExpressionAttribute`, then yes

Comment: Is there a more simple way to do this? If I inherit from ValidationAttribute for example?

Comment: AFAIK, It needs to be as per the code in my comment above.

Comment: Ok, can you answer the question with your code so I can set it as correct please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register your attribute in `global.asax`. In its `Application_Start()` method, add the following code:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(PositiveDecimalAtt‌​ribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your help ;)