# Custom validation attribute not working both client and server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I wrote a custom validation that inherit from range validation attribute but it's not working. all the other validation for this proprerty works well.
This is the Atrribute code:

```
public class GraduateYearRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
{

    public GraduateYearRangeAttribute()
        : base(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Year + 3)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "bla bla";
    }
```

This is the property in the vm:

```
    [Display(Name = "Graduate Year")]
    [Required]
    [GraduateYearRange]
    public int GraduateYear { get; set; }
```

and this is the view:

```
    <div  class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GraduateYear)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GraduateYear)
    </div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working? Client side or server side or both?

Comment: Both client and server

Comment: Have you registered the attribute in global.asax? (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889661/custom-regular-expression-not-validating-on-the-client-side/34913060#34913060) for an example using an attribute derived from `RegularExpressionAttribute`)

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen!! (:

Comment: It works. but why in other apps I didn't need to do that and it worked?