# How to validate file type of HttpPostedFileBase attribute in Asp.Net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying validate a file type of `HttpPostedFileBase` attribute to check type of file but I can't do this because the validation is passing. How could I do this ?

trying

**Model**

```
public class EmpresaModel{

[Required(ErrorMessage="Choose a file .JPG, .JPEG or .PNG file")]
[ValidateFile(ErrorMessage = "Please select a .JPG, .JPEG or .PNG file")]
public HttpPostedFileBase imagem { get; set; }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.imagem)" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Escolha a imagem <img src="~/Imagens/required.png" height="6" width="6"></label>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.imagem, new { Class = "form-control", placeholder = "Informe a imagem", type = "file" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.imagem)
</div>
```

**ValidateFileAttribute**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

//validate file if a valid image
public class ValidateFileAttribute : RequiredAttribute{

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;

        if (file == null || file.ContentLength > 1 * 1024 * 1024)
        {
            return isValid;
        }

        if (IsFileTypeValid(file))
        {
            isValid = true;
        }

        return isValid;
    }

    private bool IsFileTypeValid(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        bool isValid = false;

        try
        {
            using (var img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
            {
                if (IsOneOfValidFormats(img.RawFormat))
                {
                    isValid = true;
                } 
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            //Image is invalid
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    private bool IsOneOfValidFormats(ImageFormat rawFormat)
    {
        List<ImageFormat> formats = getValidFormats();

        foreach (ImageFormat format in formats)
        {
            if(rawFormat.Equals(format))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private List<ImageFormat> getValidFormats()
    {
        List<ImageFormat> formats = new List<ImageFormat>();
        formats.Add(ImageFormat.Png);
        formats.Add(ImageFormat.Jpeg);        
        //add types here
        return formats;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your `ValidateFileAttribute` should not inherit from `RequiredAttribute`, and you also will not get client side validation. You need to create you own validation attribute that inherits from `ValidationAttribute` and implements `IClientValidatable`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how could I do this ? do you have any example ?

Comment: But its a bit unclear what your wanting to validate - your `file.ContentLength > 1 * 1024 * 1024` suggest you want a maximum file size (file type and file size validation are 2 separate things and need to be 2 separate attributes)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because your attribute inherits from and existing attribute, it would need to be registered in `global.asax` (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889661/custom-regular-expression-not-validating-on-the-client-side/34913060#34913060) for an example), however **do not** do that in your case. Your validation code does not work, and a file type attribute should not be inheriting from `RequiredAttribute` - it needs to inherit from `ValidationAttribute` and if you want client side validation, then it also needs to implement `IClientValidatable`. An attribute to validate file types would be (note this code if for a property which is `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` and validates each file in the collection)

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FileTypeAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string _DefaultErrorMessage = "Only the following file types are allowed: {0}";
    private IEnumerable<string> _ValidTypes { get; set; }

    public FileTypeAttribute(string validTypes)
    {
        _ValidTypes = validTypes.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim().ToLower());
        ErrorMessage = string.Format(_DefaultErrorMessage, string.Join(" or ", _ValidTypes));
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files = value as IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>;
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach(HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                if (file != null && !_ValidTypes.Any(e => file.FileName.EndsWith(e)))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
                }
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "filetype",
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("validtypes", string.Join(",", _ValidTypes));
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

It would be applied to a property as

```cs
[FileType("JPG,JPEG,PNG")]
public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Attachments { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```cs
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attachments, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Attachments)
```

The following scripts are then required for client side validation (in conjunction with `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

```js
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('filetype', ['validtypes'], function (options) {
    options.rules['filetype'] = { validtypes: options.params.validtypes.split(',') };
    options.messages['filetype'] = options.message;
});

$.validator.addMethod("filetype", function (value, element, param) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
        var extension = getFileExtension(element.files[i].name);
        if ($.inArray(extension, param.validtypes) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

function getFileExtension(fileName) {
    if (/[.]/.exec(fileName)) {
        return /[^.]+$/.exec(fileName)[0].toLowerCase();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that you code is attempting to also validate the maximum size of the file which needs to be a separate validation attribute. For an example of a validation attribute that validates the maximum allowable size, refer [this article](http://www.bradwestness.com/2014/09/24/client-side-file-upload-validation/).

In addition, I recommend [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) as a good guide to creating custom validation attributes

Comment: Turns out some complex Javascript coding to enable (file type) client side validation. Just saying.

Comment: ```javascript
$.validator.addMethod("filetype", function (value, element, param) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
        var extension = getFileExtension(element.files[0].name);
        if ($.inArray(extension, param.validtypes) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

should be 'element.files[i].name

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that EndsWith is case-sensitive by default. So I would change this:

```
if (file != null && !_ValidTypes.Any(e => file.FileName.EndsWith(e)))
```

to this

```
if (file != null && !_ValidTypes.Any(e => file.FileName.EndsWith(e, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
```