# ASP.NET C# implement Client Side validation using Validation Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm going straight to the point here.
I'm trying to implement my server side validation on Client Side.
I'm really new to this so please bear with me.

I've tried the validation on Server side and it works pretty well, but when I add the `jqueryval` on my views it doesn't do the custom validation anymore.

Here's my code:

**Model**

```
  public class AgentViewModel : AgentModel
    {
        [Required]
        [FileSize(10240)]
        [FileTypes("jpg,jpeg,png")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase photo { get; set; }
        public List<ProvinceModel> Provinces { get; set; }
        public List<CityModel> Cities { get; set; }
    }
```

**Custom Validation**

```
 public class FileTypesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly List<string> _types;

        public FileTypesAttribute(string types)
        {
            _types = types.Split(',').ToList();
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return true;

            var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension((value as HttpPostedFileBase).FileName).Substring(1);
            return _types.Contains(fileExt, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Invalid file type. Only the following types {0} are supported.", String.Join(", ", _types));
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Agent", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div id="preview">
                    <img src="~/Content/Assets/no-image.png" id="profile_image" class="img-thumbnail" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.photo, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.photo)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MiddleName)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MiddleName)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProvinceID)
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProvinceID, new SelectList(Model.Provinces, "ProvinceID", "Description"), "Select Province", new { @class = "form-control province" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProvinceID)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CityID)
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityID, new SelectList(Model.Cities, "CityID", "Description"), "Select City", new { @class = "form-control city" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CityID)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Street)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Street, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Street)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactNumber)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactNumber)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employer)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employer, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Employer)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmployerContactNumber)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployerContactNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmployerContactNumber)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AgentID)
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Agent")" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                    <button type="submit" class="@(Model.IsNew ? "btn  btn-primary" : "btn btn-success")">@(Model.IsNew ? "Save" : "Update")</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        @section scripts
        {
            @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@
        }
    }
```

when I add the `jqueryval` the validation on `FileTypes` and `FileSize` doesn't work anymore.. I'm guessing that it cannot read the `FileTypes` and `FileSize` Validation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't work at all, or just doesn't work client-side? You haven't written any implementation of your custom attribute in JavaScript so there's not going to be any client-side validation without that.

Comment: @WillRay it only works on server side... but when I add the `jqueryvalidation` it doesn't fire the `FileTypes` and `FileSize` validation anymore... and I am really new to `asp.net mvc` so please bear with m,e

Comment: Sam where have you added the jQuery code can you show?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh what do you mean?... I really am not familiar with this yet.. what I did is just create a serverside validation.. I haven't created a Client Side Validation yet... I am planning if it is possible to use my server side validation as client side validation also..

Comment: You must have the JavaScript/jQuery code somewhere for the client side validation. Check your bundle config file, if it shows the path of the file there.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh I guess that is the problem.. I thought first that if I created a server side validation and just put the `jqueryval` on my view it'll read my validation... but I guess there's more to it..

Comment: Your `FileTypesAttribute` needs to implement `IClientValidatable` and you need to write the scripts to add methods to the `jQuery.validator`. Refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: For an example of this attribute, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199870/how-to-validate-file-type-of-httppostedfilebase-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4/40200034#40200034) which includes a link to a `FileSizeAttribute`

Comment: @StephenMuecke your solution works really great.. thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi sir, how about if I do this on filesize?...do I need to add new adapters and addmethod?

Comment: @SamTengWong, Did you look at the [Client-side File Upload Size Validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.bradwestness.com/2014/09/24/client-side-file-upload-validation/) link in the dupe? - it has the full code for implementing a `FileSizeAttribute` including the scripts