# How to highlight a custom element created in helper method when it has validation errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a html helper method for a file input. I want to show an error message for this field when the file is not in correct format etc.

Here is the code of this helper method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FileInputFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,  
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributesWrapper = null
        , bool isTheNameBold = false, bool isTheNameItalic = false) where TValue : HttpPostedFileBase
    { 

        var routeValueDictionaryWrapper = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributesWrapper);
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        string name = metadata.DisplayName;


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            name = metadata.PropertyName;
        }

        html.SetValidationMessageElement(name);

        html.SetValidationSummaryMessageElement(name);

    ............
}
```

I can see there two methods `SetValidationMessageElement` and `SetValidationSummaryMessageElement` but I am not quite sure how to use them and if they are for this purpose.

The validation error message should be shown in standard format like for textboxes etc where the border gets highlighted in red and there is a message in right side of the element.

Anybody has any idea how to use those methods or let me know which is the best way to handle this ?

**EDIT**

I need an error message like in the image below. For textboxes the `TextBoxFor()` shows the errors if there is any but I dont know exaclty how does it do that.

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to validate here? A `HtmlHelper` is not for validatiion (although it can add the necessary `data-val-*` attributes for unobtrusive client side validation). You need to apply a validation attribute to your property and use the standard `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` to display the error.

Comment: For example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199870/how-to-validate-file-type-of-httppostedfilebase-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4/40200034#40200034) shows a validation attribute for a file type.

Comment: The validation rules will be applied in a custom attribute but how does `Html.ValidationMessageFor()` know how to highlight this custom field ? Is there any thing I need to do or this method handles it for me ?

Comment: No, you do not do anything in your helper method - its not even clear why you have the helper (at best all you can do is generate an `<input type="file" ... />` which you can just as easily do with `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty, new { type = "file" })`

Comment: And what do you mean _The validation rules will be applied in a custom attribute_? The rules get applied from `ValidationAttributes` automatically by the `HtmlHelper`

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try your method and see if there is any error message or red border shown. For the part when you say why I would need a custom html helper method it is a bit complicated because I do not generate only `<input>` element in there. There are a few things more I need to generate and it is widely used in the system that`s why I thought to make a helper method.

Comment: Well, I thought I need to create a custom Attribute to keep all that validation logic inside and then mark the property in model with that Attribute

Comment: In that case, an extension method is fine, but you still need to return as part of the html, the output generated by `@Html.TextBoxFor(expression,new { type = "file" })` so that the correct `data-val-*` attributes are added based on the validation attributes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136501/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rajmond-burgaj).