# .NET MVC 4: File Upload Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I am implementing a file upload mechanism using .net MVC, where the file upload is a html input with type file, I am using the controller to save to file, the param the controller receives is a httppostedfilebase.

My question is what is the best way to validate the file upload? there is lots out there on stackoverflow and the web saying its best to mime sniff and check the file extension etc I am looking for a modern way t do this.

What I do so far:

check file size
save away from web root
save as a different name

What is the best way to validate the type of file, e.g. doc/docx/pdf/rtf/txt to try and avid mime spoofing and malicious files?

I am trying to avoid a magic number approach too

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199870/how-to-validate-file-type-of-httppostedfilebase-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4/40200034#40200034) for a file type attribute which also includes a link to a file size attribute

Comment: Worked perfectly, I had used the library from here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MVC-File-upload-unobtrusive-d0099c30 to follow your approach

Comment: Not as a substitute, but as an augmentation; you can do javascript validation client side as well

Comment: @MadMyche, Bith links in the comments above do both client and server side validation :)