# How to correctly upload file and restrict uploaded file type in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to implement "Upload File" functionality in ASP.NET MVC 5. But I am facing two issues.

**Question 1** How to strongly type File Upload to a model property?

**Question 2** How to Allow only certain file type upload?

Below is my attempt:

**Model**

```
    public class Resume
    {
        [Key]
        public int ResumeId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string ContentType { get; set; }

        public byte[] Content { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Uploaded")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
   }
```

**View File:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Resume", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Resume</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Upload Resume", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" id="upload" name="uploadedResume" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Resume resume, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedResume)
    {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (uploadedResume != null && uploadedResume.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var tempresume = new Resume
                    {
                        FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadedResume.FileName),
                        ContentType = uploadedResume.ContentType,
                        datetime = System.DateTime.Now
                    };
                    using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(uploadedResume.InputStream))
                    {
                        tempresume.Content = reader.ReadBytes(uploadedResume.ContentLength);
                    }
                    _context.Resumes.Add(tempresume);
                }
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ResumeCenter");
    }
```

Above code is working as expeected, But I could not strongly type the file upload. Also can I use some sort of `Data Annotation` to restrict file upload to `pdf only`. Or [FoolProof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) to apply restriction.

Comment: Your view model (always use a view model when editing data) should contain a property `public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }` and in the view `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })`

Comment: Then you can create an apply a `[FileType]` validation attribute to your property - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199870/how-to-validate-file-type-of-httppostedfilebase-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4/40200034#40200034) for an example

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I will try to implement as per your suggestion. I followed this article https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files  . It did not have file upload strongly bound.

Comment: I thought I will add a property to my Resume (Model) class itself. But as soon as I add the property when I run migration, I get error as "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet"

Comment: It needs to be applied to a view model - your editing data so ALWAYS use a view model

Comment: Sir, one basic question. You have 4 property in a Model. And there is a form where you will take user input for all these 4 property. SO, even in this case I should make a viewmodel. I thought we should make viewModel when the input form encompasses different property spread multipl models.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152690/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-unbreakable).