# How to add error messages of TempData[] to an array and display it in view as using ValidationSummary?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I am very new in MVC and I am trying to upload a file using file uploader (I am using ExcelDataReader package for this) which I was able to  but the issue is I am trying to handle the possible errors while uploading a file. In other words, I want to display all my error messages together like in ValidationSummary. And, I came to realize that ValidationSummary works only for ModelState error or property error. Similarly, I am trying to display all error messages from my controller to the view. Can any of you tell me or redirect me how to handle it?
Following is code for my controller and view.

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, int? grp = null)
{
    try
    {
        blah blah blah
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {                
        if (ex is DbEntityValidationException)
            TempData["Msg"] = "file exceeded the allowed character length.";
        if (ex is HeaderException)
            TempData["Msg"] = "corrupted";
        if (ex is OutOfMemoryException)
            TempData["Msg"] = "too large!";
        else
            TempData["Msg"] = "Error" + error;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

.

```
<div class="col-md-12 well" id="upload">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionXYZ", "ControllerABC", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {           
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.Message))
            {
                <div class="col-md-12 alert @(ViewBag.Message.Contains("success") ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger")">
                    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

                </div>
            }

            <div class="form-group ">
                <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                    <label class="control-label">Submit File:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file form-control">
                        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required="required">                        
                    </label>                        
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: `TempData` is specifically for *passing data from one request to the subsequent request*. It is not a replacement for a model or `ViewData`, which send the data from the controller to the view. By default, `TempData` is backed by session state, which is [very wasteful to use when you don't actually need it](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/).

Comment: You do not redirect if something is invalid - you return the view and display error messages so that the user can correct them - and you display the error messages by adding `ModelState` errors.

Comment: And you validate the data before saving so that you do not make unnecessary database calls. And things like file size etc can be simply handled by using validation attributes so that you get both client and server side validation. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199870/how-to-validate-file-type-of-httppostedfilebase-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4/40200034#40200034) for an example of a `[FileType]` attribute, which also includes a link to a `[FileSize]` attribute